# JSON to CSV iterate through nested objects and map value to key

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, converters

I do have a json in the format of (but with even more/deeper nested objects)

```json
{
    "Group": {
        "Group1": {
            "GroupA": {
                "value": "#fffff",
                "type": "color"

            },
            "GroupB": {
                "value": "#c2c2c2",
                "type": "color"

            },
            "GroupC": {
                "Group_XY": {
                    "value": "#aw13ma",
                    "type": "color"
                }

            }

        },
        "Group2":{
            "GroupA": {
                "value": "#ff123f",
                "type": "color"

            },
            "GroupB": {
                "value": "#fffff",
                "type": "color"

            },
            "GroupD": {
                "value": "#ababab",
                "type": "color"
                
            }

        },
        "Group3": {
            "GroupA": {
                "value": "#fffff",
                "type": "color"

            },
            "GroupC": {
                "Group_XY": {
                    "value": "#12a3ma",
                    "type": "color"
                }

            },
            "GroupD": {
                "value": "#fffff",
                "type": "color"
                
            }

        },
        "Group4": {
            "GroupA": {

            },
            "GroupB": { 
                "value": "#c2c2c2",
                "type": "color"

            },
            "GroupE": {
                "Group_XX": {
                    "Group_A1": {
                        "value": "#12a3ma",
                        "type": "color"
                    }
                }
                
            }

        }
    }  
}
```

what i want to achieve is a csv/table output to compare:

|  |  |  | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GroupA |  |  | #fffff | #ff123f | #fffff |  |
| GroupB |  |  | #c2c2c2 | #fffff |  | #c2c2c2 |
| GroupC |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Group_XY |  | #aw13ma |  | #12a3ma |  |
| GroupD |  |  |  |  | #fffff |  |
| GroupE |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Group_XX |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Group_A1 |  |  |  | #12a3ma |

so i figured that python and pandas might be the correct way to kick it off.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('colorDate.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
pd.json_normalize(data,max_level=0)
```

gets me

| Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | Group4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {'GroupA': {'value': '#fffff', 'type': 'color'... | {'GroupA': {'value': '#ff123f', 'type': 'color... | {'GroupA': {'value': '#fffff', 'type': 'color'... | {'GroupA': {}, 'GroupB': {'value': '#c2c2c2', ... |

now i need to transform the all the keys for the next level to rows?!

Comment: What does "qc" mean? And why is this tagged `python` if you're doing it in a shell script?

Comment: you are totally right, i was playing arround with different methods and and i started with python and pandas ... and ended with with bash... typo in my frustration. im sorry

Comment: "because I lost the parten"? What is parten? Please update the question with the desired output.

Comment: @Barmar again you are right. i was way to quick. pure frustration. i hope no it is clear what i'm aiming for. 
i don't care about the tool stack. so python might be an option aswell ... i don't know anyore

Comment: This looks a bit complicated for bash and jq. I'd recommend python and pandas.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start implementing this in a main stream language such as Java, C#, or Python.

Comment: Isn't the cell in row `GroupD` column `Group2` missing the value `#ababab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i don't care about the tool stack

So, why not use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), then?
It can transform JSON with ease, and even generate your desired output format using the `@csv` builtin and the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option.

```bash
.Group | to_entries | reduce (
  .[] | (.value | paths(objects) as $p | [$p, getpath($p).value]) + [.key]
) as [$path, $value, $column] ({}; ."\($path)"[$column] = $value)

| (keys | map(fromjson) | sort) as $paths
| ($paths | map(length) | max)  as $width
| (map(keys[]) | unique)        as $heads

| [(range($width) | null), $heads[]], ($paths[] as $path
  | ($path | .[:-1] |= map(null)) + [range($path | $width - length) | null]
  + [."\($path)"[$heads[]]]
) | @csv
```

```
,,,"Group1","Group2","Group3","Group4"
"GroupA",,,"#fffff","#ff123f","#fffff",
"GroupB",,,"#c2c2c2","#fffff",,"#c2c2c2"
"GroupC",,,,,,
,"Group_XY",,"#aw13ma",,"#12a3ma",
"GroupD",,,,"#ababab","#fffff",
"GroupE",,,,,,
,"Group_XX",,,,,
,,"Group_A1",,,,"#12a3ma"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9Q7uZL7tNBZ)

---

A personal suggestion: For better readability, I would "merge" those "blank" lines as they provide no additional information, while combining (and if necessary, duplicating) the path items on the row headers. For this, extend `paths(objects)` to `paths(objects | has("value"))` to only descend to items of value, and reveal the full path by changing `($path | .[:-1] |= map(null))` to just `$path`:

```bash
.Group | to_entries | reduce (
  .[] | (.value | paths(objects | has("value")) as $p | [$p, getpath($p).value]) + [.key]
) as [$path, $value, $column] ({}; ."\($path)"[$column] = $value)

| (keys | map(fromjson) | sort) as $paths
| ($paths | map(length) | max)  as $width
| (map(keys[]) | unique)        as $heads

| [(range($width) | null), $heads[]], ($paths[] as $path
  | $path + [range($path | $width - length) | null]
  + [."\($path)"[$heads[]]]
) | @csv
```

```
,,,"Group1","Group2","Group3","Group4"
"GroupA",,,"#fffff","#ff123f","#fffff",
"GroupB",,,"#c2c2c2","#fffff",,"#c2c2c2"
"GroupC","Group_XY",,"#aw13ma",,"#12a3ma",
"GroupD",,,,"#ababab","#fffff",
"GroupE","Group_XX","Group_A1",,,,"#12a3ma"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DPBPluIgKrl)

Comment: You Sir, you are just awesome. it worked perfectly.